# Terminal do VS Code não lê palavras acentuadas

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, acentuação, caracteres, mint

Aperto a tecla para acentuar e mesmo assim aparece sem acento[image: print do terminal vs code]

Já no terminal do sistema funciona normal
[image: print terminal mint]

Comment: qual o seu O.S?

Comment: Linux Mint 20, Kernel 5.4.0-58